# A user massively tries to add irrelevant tags (which I can see while reviewing suggested edits), should I do anything about it?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

Today while reviewing suggested edits I stumbled upon a user who adds mostly irrelevant tags and comments that like "added other tags for more viewers. It will help you to get more views and better quality answers".

I've seen that thrice, rejected each one; couple of screenshots below, my bad, saved only one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694364/my-css-document-doesnt-change-html) to a question. Here's [their suggestions list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3704489/star?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and as you can see, there are other similar rejected edits. Is there a way to notify them about their.. mistakes? Should I do anything about it?

[image]
[image]

PS to those who's interested: I've raised a flag and Martijn Pieters♦ rolled back all but 2 edits; however, I'm unaware if Martijn has somehow notified Star so that they realize the problem.

PPS see the comment by Cody Gray♦.

Comment: Reject and edit.

Comment: @Braiam yeap, I've done that, but the guy seems not to understand the problem despite the fact that they already have a number of rejected edits like that. So, I'm asking about a more.. consistent response. What Servy describes sounds good enough.

Comment: *the guy seems not to understand the problem despite the fact that they already have a number of rejected edits* - Too many of them are actually getting approved no matter how obviously bad the tag edit is. (I think the "more views" bit in their edit summary is why the OPs in some cases are going ahead and approving them.)

Comment: Weird, there's a no trivial amount of reviews that were approved by the authors, which is weird.

Comment: Maybe trying to get Copy-Editor gold badge very quickly.

Comment: Yes, a moderator has reached out to the user. Flags really do work! :-) Thanks for caring so much about quality on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can we have a canonical, "Just flag it," question to close these as dupes, please?

Comment: @jpmc26 it's not quite clear what do you mean by *it*. If there were a flagging mechanism inside the review interface, there won't be this question. With current interface, it's not obvious what's a proper action, so I've asked for assistance.

Comment: @YakovL That the review queue lacks the ability to flag is a well worn complaint. As for what to flag, anytime you can't flag the problem "thing" directly, you always just pick a *related* item and flag it with a custom flag. (E.g., flag one of the posts the user put a bad edit suggestion on in this case.) This is canonical advice for a *wide* variety of problems. My point is we don't need 50 bazillion questions all saying that. Not your fault if you don't follow Meta, but it's still kind of annoying.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a *related* item. You can flag one of your own posts for all a moderator cares, as long as your flag explanation is sufficiently clear about the problem you want to bring to our attention. Include links to the relevant review queue(s). But yeah, the standard advice is to flag one of the posts made by the "offender". I sort of agree with @jpmc26 here, because calling people out on Meta tends to have negative side-effects. That's why moderator flags exist and are private.

Comment: @jpmc26 yeah, I see your point; my point is if there's too many such questions that have this *obvious* answer, than it is not obvious enough. Look at it from my position and let's assume there's no meta: how can I figure out that I should use that flag? I can see only 2 scenarios: I've read all the articles in help including https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging ; or I've read wording of the flag *very* carefully and realized it can be used for an item not being flagged. Note: I've flagged a number of posts (Marshal). So the question is: what may make more users know this simple way?

Comment: @jpmc26 actually, I've got some ideas. One is – give another bronze badge for reading the whole help section. Or a silver one for those with say 1000 reputation for reading that. Another way may be to add more to the flag description: like "this flag can be used to notify a moderator about a problem in *any* part of SO, but it shouldn't be the one that can be handled using other flags" or something like that. The point is, when I raised my first flags, I've read the wordings rather carefully, but the "moderator" flag wasn't used almost at all so I hasn't came to my mind in this case.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just flag one of the post and explain the situation to a moderator.  They'll be able to handle the situation.

Comment: Do you mean the post to which the edit was proposed? So it's ok that I flag not the edit (edits can't be flagged) but some other item (question) so that a moderator will take a look at the context and decide for themselves, right? It's ok even if the edit gets rejected (and hence there's nothing about it in the versions story), but I have to provide the missing links to the description, correct?

Comment: @YakovL Yes, you have to flag the post, and yes, you're going to need to provide links to the edits in your flag, as that's crucial information for the moderator when evaluating your flag.

Comment: Did you not used to be a mod @Servy ?

Comment: @Ian I have never been a mod, no.